# How to select latest checked radio button in multiple radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this from, how to select with jquery the latest radiobutton was selected by the user

```
<form id = "myform">
<h3>Time to work?</h3>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="work" value="Hourly" />
    <input type="radio" name="work" value="Daily" />
    <input type="radio" name="work" value="Weekly" />
  </p>
<h3>Your Age?</h3>   
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="old" />
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="young" />
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="child" />
  </p>
</form>
```

I tried

```
$('input:checked', '#myform').val();
```

and

```
$('input[type='radio']:checked', '#myform').val();
```

but it always select the only value of the first question! any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
    alert(jQuery(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's ok but I've too much questions, so Is it logical to repeat these lines of code for each question? I want a script to select the latest selected one only

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "click" listener to each radio button. Then simply store the value in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have some syntax errors with single and double quotes as you can probably notice by the syntax highlighting in your code. Also you'd need to use the name attribute, no just `input`:

```
$('input[name="age"]:checked').val()
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/bHWv7/

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()` should give you selected radio button value.
Also `$('input[name=myradiobutton]:radio:checked')` should work fine.